# Azure devops selenium testplan

Tags: selenium, automation, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, test-plan

I have created a test plan for 10 test cases. I have automated 5 test cases in visual studios 2019. I need to run the automated testcase from testplan, as that i have to execute the remaining manual testcase and failed automation tests manually in the testplan after the run overs.

Answer (score 0):

We can run all tests in Azure DevOps.The only Failed test cases can be re-run using the Azure DevOps VS test task.

If you want to provide a test plan, you can use "Test filter criteria" option in the VS test task

[image: Vs-Test]